# Handling unexpected array/object in string field - ElasticSearch

Tags: php, elasticsearch, logging

Having ElasticSearch handling logs is great.
But having a program that sends different data types for same field is not so much...

For example:

One query could be

```
send('id' => '123')
```

and another

```
send('id' => ['123'])
```

This will fail for second send since Elastic will reject it even with `ignore_malformed: true` (field type is set to text).

> Same would happen with object

Is there any other way to give more dynamic value setting for fields?

Or should I just go through code and change all queries...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no particular data type, that is defined for [array](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/array.html) values in elasticsearch. You just need to make sure that the array value contains the same type of values.

Adding a working example with index mapping and data

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "id": {
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Data 1:**

```
{
  "id": "123"
}
```

**Index Data 2:**

```
{
  "id": [
    "123",
    "56"
  ]
}
```

Both these documents will be successfully indexed, without any exception

**Edit 1:**

**If you just want the documents to be indexed (and not searched), then you can set the `id` type to object with [`"enabled": false`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/enabled.html). This will index all the format of data (text, array, object)**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "id": {
        "type": "object",
        "enabled": false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Following documents will be indexed using the above mapping

**Object type:**

```
{
  "id": {
    "age": 50,
    "name": {
      "first": "John"
    }
  }
}
```

**Array Type:**

```
{
  "id": [
    "123",
    "56"
  ]
}
```

**String type:**

```
{
  "id": "123"
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. But how could I handle array with KVP ('idNum' => "123")? Also what to do if Object comes instead of array?

Comment: @lucian24 You can try the other way around. Please go through the updated part of the answer

Comment: This fixes everything. Thank you!